# Separate Content from Presentation using Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

Reference: [HTML5Rocks Shadow DOM 101](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

Question: **How can I replace contents of `<content></content` from the `#nameTagTemplate` template?**

Problem: Currently my javascript replaces all of the template elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="todo">Hey I'm a todo app</div>
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
    <style>
      .outer {
        border: 2px solid brown;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="boilerplate">
        Hi! My name is
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <content></content>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**js file**

```
var todoEl = document.querySelector('.todo');
var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var root = todoEl.createShadowRoot()
root.appendChild(clone);
root.textContent = 'Shellie'; // this line replaces all nodes in template.
// I would like root.textContent to just replace the content tag elements.
```

**Comment: Update still doesnt work**

```
// template logic goes here
var todoEl = document.querySelector('.todo');
var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
clone.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].textContent='123';
var root = todoEl.createShadowRoot();
root.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: `clone.getElementsByTagName("content")[0].textContent=123`?

Comment: sorry, the <content> tag is special, i  forgot that. any other tag name works, ex: http://jsfiddle.net/kqj8640r/  more info:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you edit the `textContent` of the `.todo` element then it works as expected.

```js
var todoEl = document.querySelector('.todo');
var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var root = todoEl.createShadowRoot();
root.appendChild(clone);
todoEl.textContent = 'Shellie';
```

```js
var todoEl = document.querySelector('.todo');
var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
var root = todoEl.createShadowRoot();
root.appendChild(clone);
todoEl.textContent = 'Shellie';
```

```html
<div class="todo">Hey I'm a todo app</div>
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
  <style>
    .outer {
      border: 2px solid brown;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="boilerplate">
      Hi! My name is
    </div>
    <div class="name">
      <h3><content></content></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the [html5rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) this is done by querying for the DOM element when the button was clicked. It also says "*the insertion point cherry-picks content from the shadow host to present at that point*", which means the content on the shadow host is what lives inside of the `<content></content>` element.

Comment: Thanks man! This makes perfect sense! I need to read more carefully Yay!